# Unable to get URL parameter value from pretty URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get the value of `$_GET['p']` from the link domain.com/profile/nick. I am using htaccess to get parameter from pretty url. What is the problem?

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)*$ ./profile.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning `MultiViews` off:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9+-]+)/?$ profile.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.